# Элементарный вопрос по Python по классам

Tags: python

```
class a():
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x
    def xpr(n):
        print(self.x*n)

a=a('rt')
a.xpr(10)
rtrtrtrtrtrtrtrtrtrt

class b(a):
    def reconstr(self):
        y = self.x*2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#20>", line 1, in <module>
    class b(a):
TypeError: a.__init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

Good day! Why there is an error ? It must be a simple example of inheritance(наследование) Is there any difference in versions of language or what ? (code text - copy-paste text from shell)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в строке:

```
a = a("rt")
```

С этого момента в переменой `a` лежит не класс, а экземпляр этого класса. В этом вся проблема. Либо измените название переменной, либо название класса.

Comment: @Kromster исправил

Comment: Вот поэтому в питоне и рекомендуют классы с большой буквы называть... )  Чтобы хоть с переменными путаницы не было.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку. Невнимательно посмотрел. и Взаимоисключения не было никакого